# почему не срабатывает task stylus при запсуке task watch

Tags: gulp

Всем добра, столкнулся с проблемой, при запсуке таска watch не срабатывает task stylus а browserSync cрабатывает при изменении html. он даже не компилируется не говоря о том чтоб автоматически меняться.Если запускать именно task stylus то он работает а вот совместно нет. я совсем новичек, буду благодарен за терпение и помощь. 
код

```js
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
 stylus      = require('gulp-stylus'),
 browserSync = require('browser-sync');



gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
 var files = [
  'app/**/*.css',
  'app/index.html'
 ];
 browserSync.init(files,{
  server: {
   baseDir: './app/'
  }
 });
});
gulp.task('stylus', function(){
 return gulp.src('app/stylus/**/*.styl')
 .pipe(stylus())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
 .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: 'app/css/*.css'}))
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browser-sync', 'stylus'), function(){
 gulp.watch('app/stylus/**/*.styl', gulp.series('stylus'));
 gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
 gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', browserSync.reload)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых для чего вы поднимаете сервер на уровень выше самого **gulpfile** ? Это разумеется ваше дело но почти всегда будет удобнее если **gulpfile** находиться на самом верхнем уровне рядом с папкой "**app**".

Я не понимаю зачем вы передаете `gulp.series('browser-sync', 'stylus')` в объявлении таска "**watch**". Если вы хотите получить последовательное выполнение до "**watch**" используйте для этого таск "**default**".

Вы не используете "**gulp-concat**" и "**gulp-autoprefixer**" ? в этом случае вы не используете все преимущества **gulp**, советую вам ознакомится и доустановить эти пакеты.

Я мог бы сказать почему ваш код не работает но вам лучше будет взглянуть на чуть более продвинутую логику для вашего **gulpfile**.

```js
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    stylus       = require('gulp-stylus'),
    concat       = require('gulp-concat'),
    cleancss     = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
        notify: false
    })
});

function bsReload(done) { browserSync.reload(); done(); };

gulp.task('stylus', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/stylus/**/*.styl')
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({overrideBrowserslist: ['>= 0.01%']}))
    .pipe(cleancss({
        compatibility: 'ie8',
        level: {
            1: { specialComments: 0 },
            2: { removeDuplicateFontRules: false }
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/stylus/**/*.styl', gulp.parallel('stylus'));
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', gulp.parallel(bsReload));
    gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', gulp.parallel(bsReload));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('stylus', 'browser-sync', 'watch'));
```

Также рекомендую посмотреть на полный пример хорошего **gulpfile**: https://github.com/agragregra/OptimizedHTML-5

Там по ссылке на автора можно найти подробное видео на русском.